# Start animation not resuming after hover animation ends in Spline web

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, spline

I created a 3D element in Spline web and added a start and a hover animation. I've set the loop of the start animation to infinite; however, it doesn't resume after the hover animation ends (when the mouse leaves element). What may be the issue?